# Jhipster updating fake-data csv files after entity updates

Tags: jhipster

I just updated my entities via an updated jdl file. After successfully running 'jhipster import-jdl myUpdatedJdl.jdl', I've noticed my csv files under liquibase/fake-data were not updated. Is there an easy way to update my fake-data csv files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rebuild you project. It should be enough

```
mvn clean install
```

or using maven wrapper

```
mvnw
```

and check if you still have proper configuration in application-dev.yml file:

```
 liquibase:
# Remove 'faker' if you do not want the sample data to be loaded automatically
contexts: dev, faker
```

Faker must be there for generating some sample data